Using an imaginary conducting shell of infinite radius to calculate capacitance of a spherical conductor
This is a statement from Serway's Modern Physics which I don't understand. It tries to explain capaticance for a single conductor.
Imagine a single spherical charged conductor. The electric field lines around this conductor are exactly the same as if there were a conducting, spherical shell of infinite radius, concentric with the sphere and carrying a charge of the same magnitude but opposite sign. Therefore, we can identify the imaginary shell as the second conductor of a two-conductor capacitor. The electric potential of the sphere of radius $a$ is simply $k_\epsilon Q/a$ and setting $V=0$ for the infinitely large shell gives
$$C=\frac{Q}{\Delta V}=\frac{Q}{k_\epsilon Q/a}=4\pi \epsilon_0 a.$$
Why does the conducting shell have the same electric field lines as the sphere?  And why does this property allow us to identify the imaginary shell as the second conductor of a two-conductor capacitor?

If I got your question right, that's because the electric charge in the inner sphere accumulates in the surface layer, and thus it's (approximately?) equivalent to a thin shell.
In this spherical symmetric setup, centered in the center of the spheres/shells, the electric field in a point $\mathbf{r}$ only depends on charge at $\mathbf{r}_c$, with $|\mathbf{r}_c| < |\mathbf{r}|$.

I get that we can replace the inner sphere with a point charge at the center, but how are the field lines for the outer shell with negative charge the same as this point charge?
